# Eclipse Bug - Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<MatchedArticle> to Class<? extends JsonSerializer<?>>

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a class like this:

```
@JsonSerialize(using=MatchedArticle.class)
public class MatchedArticle extends JsonSerializer<MatchedArticle>{
```

It builds fine with maven, but Eclipse reports the following error:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<MatchedArticle> to Class<? extends JsonSerializer<?>>

which is weird because *MatchedArticle* really do extend *JsonSerializer*

Any hints on how to turn off this exact validation in Eclipse?

Comment: I came across this question only now. I tried to reproduce the problem, but couldn't. If you still see this: which Eclipse version are you using? What compiler settings (compliance)?

Comment: came through the same bug (on Jackson @JsonSerialize too), if you've found your answer, please share it with us !

Answer (score 3):

Came through the same issue.You may have imported the wrong class/package.

In my case
**Mistakenly I imported this**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
```

**instead of this correct solution**

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. That may have solved my problem, but I handled it differently. I'll look into it if I have the time.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles upon this question. I have not tried out the solution given by Vijay. It would be natural to try that out first.

I solved it by extending SimpleModule, and inside it I added a few nested empty mixin classes.

```
public class MyModule extends SimpleModule {

      @JsonSerialize(using = ObjectSerializer.class)
      @JsonDeserialize(using = ObjectDeserializer.class)
      public static class ObjectMixin {}

      @JsonSerialize(using = NaturalKeySerializer.class)
      @JsonDeserialize(using = NaturalKeyDeserializer.class)
      public static class NaturalKeyMixin {}

      @JsonSerialize(using = ChangeSerializer.class)
      @JsonDeserialize(using = ChangeDeserializer.class)
      public static class ChangeMixin {}

      @JsonSerialize(using = ViolationSerializer.class)
      public static class ViolationMixin {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have come across the same issue. Here are my 2 classes in a very much larger project:

```
package ws.daley.hollow.validation;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;

@Target({ TYPE, ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = PasswordMatchesValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface PasswordMatches
{
    String message() default "Passwords don't match";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

and

```
package ws.daley.hollow.validation;

import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

import ws.daley.hollow.persistence.admin.model.User;
import ws.daley.hollow.web.admin.dto.UserDto;

public class PasswordMatchesValidator implements ConstraintValidator<PasswordMatches, Object>
{
    @Override
    public void initialize(@SuppressWarnings("unused") final PasswordMatches constraintAnnotation) {/* */}

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(final Object obj, final ConstraintValidatorContext context)
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final UserDto<User> user = (UserDto<User>) obj;
        return user.getPassword().equals(user.getMatchingPassword());
    }
}
```

The following line in PasswordMatches

```
    @Constraint(validatedBy = PasswordMatchesValidator.class)
```

gets the error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<PasswordMatchesValidator> to Class<? extends ConstraintValidator<?,?>>[]
```

The code builds fine under maven both inside and outside of STS4.

I have found a temporary (and very transient) fix for the problem. Simply copy the PasswordMatches source code to the clipboard, delete the PasswordMatches class from the project, add a new class of the same name, paste the copied code back in, save and build. The problem is now gone, but only for a while. Sometime later, apparently some random occurrence causes the exact same error to reappear in exactly the same place. The above action again fixes the problem.

I am running STS4 on Eclipse. The problem did not occur before I upgraded to JDK10 from JDK8 and from STS3 to STS4, although this may be anecdotal. I suspect the problem is in the new eclipse/STS4 or it's use of language servers.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem while serializing enum constants. I resolved this problem by creating a custom module and adding serializer, deserializers to it.

```
public enum Month {
 SUNDAY("Sunny Sunday"), MONDAY("Morning Monday"), TUESDAY("Good tuesday"), WEDNESDAY("Happy Wednesday"),
 THURSDAY("Great Tuesday"), FRIDAY("Good Friday"), SATURDAY("Sleepy Saturday");

 .....
 .....
}

public class MonthSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Month> {

 @Override
 public void serialize(Month month, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers)
   throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
   .....
   .....
 }

}

public class MonthDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Month> {

 @Override
 public Month deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

 .....
 .....
 }
}

public class MonthModule extends SimpleModule{
     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

     private static final String NAME = "CustomAddressModule";
     private static final VersionUtil VERSION_UTIL = new VersionUtil() {
     };

     public MonthModule() {
             super(NAME, VERSION_UTIL.version());
             addSerializer(Month.class, new MonthSerializer());
             addDeserializer(Month.class, new MonthDeserializer());
     }
}
```

Once you defined MonthModule, register it to the ObjectMapper.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new MonthModule());
```

Referene [link](https://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.com/2020/03/jackson-handling-enums.html).